# Can AirPods be be used with multiple Charging Case units?

Tags: charging, airpods, case

Can I use one pair of AirPods with two or more Charging case units? Can I take turns charging the case, and deposit AirPods into either without any bother?

- [Apple sells a Charging Case](https://support.apple.com/airpods/repair/service) for USD $69.
- Apple announced their [intention to soon sell](https://www.macworld.com/article/3224389/mobile-accessories/apple-airpower-features-specs-price-faq.html) a [Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(standard)) charging case upgrade for AirPods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple charging cases. Put the AirPods in either charging case to see the AirPod charge level and the battery level of that particular charging case. At the moment, once of my cases shows 94%. Moving the AirPods to the other case shows a 100% case charge level.